# Java FileInputStream Issues(Extra Whitespace)

Tags: java

When I use FileInputStream to input text from my spawn.txt file for a tile-based map, it adds extra whitespace in-between each line.

```java
package mapInit;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class SpawnMap {

    static char[][] spawnWorld = new char[30][30];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream spawn = new FileInputStream("Resources/Map/spawn.txt");
            int i = 0;
            int h = 0;
            int k = 0;
            while((i=spawn.read())!=-1){
                if(h == 30) {
                    h = 0;
                    k++;
                }
                spawnWorld[k][h] = (char)i;
                h++;
            }       
            spawn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) { 
            for (int j=0;j<30;j++) { 
                System.out.println(spawnWorld[i][j]); 
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

This is the result of the output loop:
[image: Output result]
This is a picture of the text file:

[image: Text File]

GitHub Link: https://github.com/WeaponGod243/Machlandia

Comment: Why do you use `FileInputStream` instead of `Scanner` ?

Comment: Since I am kind of new to Java, I didn't know that scanner could be used for file reading.

Comment: Check my answer below. `Scanner` class it's more suitable for your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Scanner` class it's more suitable for your task

> Scanner class in Java is found in the java.util package. Java provides
>   various ways to read input from the keyboard, the java.util.Scanner
>   class is one of them.
>
> The Java Scanner class breaks the input into tokens using a delimiter
>   which is whitespace by default. It provides many methods to read and
>   parse various primitive values.
>
> The Java Scanner class is widely used to parse text for strings and
>   primitive types using a regular expression. It is the simplest way to
>   get input in Java. By the help of Scanner in Java, we can get input
>   from the user in primitive types such as int, long, double, byte,
>   float, short, etc.
>
> The Java Scanner class extends Object class and implements Iterator
>   and Closeable interfaces.
>
> The Java Scanner class provides nextXXX() methods to return the type
>   of value such as nextInt(), nextByte(), nextShort(), next(),
>   nextLine(), nextDouble(), nextFloat(), nextBoolean(), etc. To get a
>   single character from the scanner, you can call next().charAt(0)
>   method which returns a single character.
>   [Source](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class)

[Scanner Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {

    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Resources/Map/spawn.txt"))) {
        // Checking if sc has another token in the file
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            // Print line
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Use a Logger to log exceptions in real projects
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You could use *Apache Commons IO* library too

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>


    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ReadTextFile {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            try {       
                File f = new File("Resources/Map/spawn.txt");

                List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(f, "UTF-8");

                for (String line : lines) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Use a Logger to log exceptions in real projects
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }        
    }
```

Comment: Since I am splitting the lines into characters, how would i put each character in its place in my array?(Thanks for the answer btw)

Comment: With the `Scanner` or the second option  you don't need to split lines. It will read the lines for you

Answer (score 0):

Change the `System.out.println` inside your loop to just `System.out.print`.

`System.out.println` will automatically add a newline character every time, even if you're only printing a single character.  `System.out.print` will take the `String` you pass in, and print it as is.

Here's a link to the official Javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-

Also, unless it's on purpose, verify you're not printing the `\n` (newline character) at the end of each line. If you actually want to start a new line at the end of each line, simply put a `System.out.println();` line after the end of the innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your codes. It seems by using this I have detected that by using FileInputStream it will produce an empty space in between the values.

```
static char[][] spawnWorld = new char[30][30];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream spawn = new FileInputStream("C:/Daniel/spawn.txt");
        int i = 0;
        int h = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while ((i = spawn.read()) != -1) {
            if (h == 30) {
                h = 0;
                k++;
            }
            spawnWorld[k][h] = (char) i;
            if (h == 19) System.out.println((char) i);
            System.out.println("[" + k + "][" + h + "] : " +  i);
            h++;
        }
        spawn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Start Printing");
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            System.out.println("[" + i + "][" + j + "] : " + spawnWorld[i][j]);
        }
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

From then on you may debug it accordingly. 
At line 19, your 'i' returns a blank space or char value i.
I would suggest to use the Scanner as your way to read the file instead.

Comment: How would you use Scanner in this situation? (Thanks for the answer btw)

Comment: Yes, Scanner it's more suitable for your task

Answer (score 0):

A text file is made up of characters on a line followed by end-of-line sequences, typically newlines or carriage returns followed by newlines. (These can also be thought of as line separators rather than line endings, and the last line might not be followed by one, depending on how the file was created.) You are reading the file character by character but you make no allowance for these end of line characters.

It doesn't make any difference whether you use `FileInputStream` or `Scanner`; the problem is, you read the file one character at a time but don't account for carriage return and newline.

For example:

```
while ((i=spawn.read()) != -1) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace((char)i)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (h == 30) {
        h = 0;
        k++;
    }
    spawnWorld[k][h] = (char)i;
    h++;
}
```

Comment: How do you disregard return and newline?

Comment: @WeaponGod243 You can check if the `char` you get back is `'\n'` or `'\r'`. Or, if you're not expecting any whitespace, you could check with `Character.isWhitespace((char)i)`.